# app engine ndb Key.get only returning the key?

Tags: app-engine-ndb

Given a Key that I construct, I would like to hit the datastore to see if it exists, but I want the cheapest (in time) way to do that. What I am looking for is like a keys only query but from get, e.g. my_key.get(keys_only=True). Does such an animal exist? It doesn't look like it to me. If not, is there some other way to achieve what I am after?

Thanks.

Comment: You may find it useful to retrieve a projection with minimal properties. Not sure if that will be faster though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this functionality does not exist.  Since not all entities are indexed, there is no shortcut -- the only way to test whether the key exists is to try to get it, and then you have the entity data available to you for free (in terms of disk operations anyway -- there's a bit of serialization cost but we're not charging for that).

PS. Are you sure you aren't trying to optimize prematurely?

Comment: Thanks Guido. In answer to your question, I'm not certain that I am not trying to optimize prematurely. But I have used appstats to make as much as much in parallel and have cut down pretty well on rpc calls. The entities that I am pulling back in this case have a TextProperty that I do not need for the view, that is what I was looking to avoid. Thanks again and thanks for the awesomeness that is ndb!

Comment: If your current Model is used for two different reasons, consider splitting it up into two separate Models, one for each purpose. You can even use the same key id for each. This way you save the unnecessary payload that the TextProperty brings.